# How to get upstream/downstream performance for Atmosphere channel within Vaadin Flow 14?

Tags: performance, vaadin-flow, atmosphere, diagnostics

We use Jetty embedded for Vaadin Flow application. I need to log or visualize Push Atmosphere channel performance for Vaadin web application. I is useful for diagnostic internet connection speed and quality for our external clients. How can i do that?
In one word, i need to measure internet connection over websocket channel, in both directions. I want to use it for connection quality indicator on application page.

Comment: The question is too vague to be answered. What exactly you need to measure? Are you sure that profiling of the Atmosphere requests would address that need?

Comment: We need to check internet connection speed between client and server in both directions. Edited question.